# Having trouble reading an HTML text file into BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to read in a saved copy of the worldometer coronavirus html page with BeautifulSoup4 and python3 (Anaconda Jupyter Notebook).  Here's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open(r"c:\data\test.html") as fp:
   soup = BeautifulSoup(fp.read(), "html.parser")
```

When I execute this I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-cd472fc11bf6> in <module>
      3 
      4 with open(r"c:\data\test.html") as fp:
----> 5     soup = BeautifulSoup(fp.read(), "html.parser")

~\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py in decode(self, input, final)
      21 class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):
      22     def decode(self, input, final=False):
---> 23         return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
     24 
     25 class StreamWriter(Codec,codecs.StreamWriter):

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 797676: character maps to 
<undefined>
```

When I read this file directly via http into BS4, it works Ok.  But, if I continue to access the page this way, I get blocked.  I am able to successfully access the page every 10 minutes directly through Chrome and have been storing them for the last week.  Now I need to be able to read them in so I can begin processing the data.  Not sure why I'm seeing this error.  Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to an unknown character for the current encoding, like "á" "ó" or so on. You have to specify python to read that with the proper deoding:

```
with open(file, encoding='utf8') as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, "html.parser")
```

Comment: could I get a tick please?